# Arduino struggling to power a large LED strip

Tags: arduino-uno, power, led, rgb-led

I'm building a [word clock](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=word%20clock&safe=active&hl=en&biw=1920&bih=1089&site=webhp&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwistvr-qbPMAhWIFJQKHTd6D4sQsAQIGQ) and its a grid of 20x20 letters, each with its own LED (I know, its absurd for just a clock). I've recently got the LED's on a strip. Its the WS2812B type, just like the neopixels. There are 3 rolls of 5m strips and a single 1m strip. When I tried to power the 1m strip, everything worked perfectly and all looked quite lovely. But when I tried the 5m strip (just one of them), this happened: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5w1lok6wa7dfvzd/IMG_0046.MOV.mov?dl=0

If you didn't see the video I recorded of it, for a second or two after powering the arduino (uno) on, it works as expected but not long after it all stops the colors and fades to red, sometimes it just instantly jumps to it, like the second time in the video. I don't know what happened but all I can guess is that the arduino is not able to power the strip properly. Any ideas on what I should do to be able to power a total of 16m of these strips?

Comment: Each LED needs 60mA. Do the math.

Comment: So that would be 24 amps right?

Comment: And now you know why they don't use 2812Bs for it.

Comment: So how in the world would I go about carrying that out?!

Comment: Use discrete RGB LEDs, and restrict them to 4mA per color. It will still be a lot of current, but far less than full 2812Bs.

Comment: I've already got the 2812Bs so it would not be ideal to change them, what can I do to make it work with what I have?

Comment: Don't run them with values higher than 50 per channel. That should keep the total current below 5A. Which will still require you to power them externally.

Comment: Alright then, so heres my thinking. The grid is 20x20, so if I have a power source every for every 2 rows (each one being 20 LED's so a total of 40 LED's for every power source). What do you think of that?

Comment: That will work, but it will still be 10 2.5A supplies.

Comment: Yeah, seems like the best option though, unless you have any other ideas I think I will have to go with that.

Comment: I'd still run them lower than full brightness. Most people can't tell the difference between 230 and 255 unless they're right next to each other, and even 100 is still decently bright.

Comment: Thats a good point actually. If I did that, is it easy to work out how much power it would need if the brightness were lowered?

Comment: The LEDs use PWM, so it's approximately linearly proportional to the value used.

Comment: Thats good to know, well thanks for your help, hopefully it will work!

Comment: @MatthewInglis according to the internet (http://web2.murraystate.edu/andy.batts/ps/PowerRatings.htm) a 250watt computer power supply would be able to supply 25A on 5V.

Comment: @MatthewInglis Just be warned that 1) with a duty cycle of 50%, instead of 24A you will have a 12A AVERAGE current; while this is the right value to pick for thermal considerations, if your power supply is not rated for 24A peak it won't work properly (because the instantaneous current will be always 24A). 2) using an ATX power supply can seem good but you COULD have some problems due to the fact that they expect some load on every rail. Usually the feedback rail is the 5V, so it should be sufficiently stable, but... Well, a dedicated 5V 25A power supply is better

Answer (score 1):

WS2812 use around 1mA when they are off. So that's already 400mA with no LED lighted. USB can supply around 500mA. So you only have 100mA available.

Each led package has three colored leds inside; Red, Green and Blue. Every color will use around 20mA when fully turned on.

So you can only turn on 5 colors at full brightness at 500mA.

Using a 2.5A supply you could go up to 105 colors, or 35 leds full white.

This would be more than enough for a word-clock, as most leds will be off.

Comment: Thats not enough for our word clock, as I said in the description our clock is 20x20, which is 400 LED's

Comment: The point is that you aren't lighting all leds at the same time. The word clock is quite useless if all leds are on all.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to power a consumer which draws more current than the arduino could provide.

To fix this, you need an transistor and a ~5V battery (e.g. 4.8V NiMh, or a stronger batteries plus suitable resistors, to not burn out the leds)

Look at this (awesome paint) shematic to understand the principle.
The arduino will switch the transistor through S2 which then closes the circuit.
Through S1, the arduino can set the LEDs values.

Note that for savety, you should also set a diode between S1 and the LEDs, so the battery cannot burn out your arduino, if the LED strip is cheap made.

The reason why the behavior at your setup differs might be because of a capacitor on the arduino which works similar to a batterie (With extreme little capacity).
The capacitor might provide enough power to run the LEDs for a very short periode. After discharging, the capacitor needs some time to recharge and thus it may vary in effect.

[image]